# Instruments launch option shows only iPad simulator

Tags: ios, xcode4.2, instruments

Instrument launch option drop down shows only iPad simulator.
I want to run a script with iPhone simulator,but the drop down does not list the iPhone simulator option.
Using Xcode 4.2 and IOS 5 on snow leopard.

I am trying to record my actions in iPhone simulator but each time i record iPad gets launched.
But manually the launch options drop down not listing iPhone simulator.It lists only iPad simulator.